# "Por muito que" X "Por mais que"

Tags: português-brasileiro

Não estou entendo a diferença entre **por muito que** e **por mais que**, embora tenha procurado sobre isso e visto alguns exemplos.

Ou seja, os seguintes exemplos têm o mesmo sentido:

> Por muito que me peça, não vou mudar a minha decisão.

> Por mais que me peça, não vou mudar a minha decisão.

> Por mais dinheiro que me ofereçam, não vendo a casa.

> Por muito dinheiro que me ofereçam, não vendo a casa.

> Por muitos anos que viva, nunca vai gastar toda a sua fortuna.

> Por mais anos que viva, nunca vai gastar toda a sua fortuna.

Obrigado!

Comment: São sinónimos, creio eu, mas “por mais que” é mais comum, pela minha experiência. Para mim, “por mais que me peça, não mudarei” parece que o falante não mudará independentemente de quanto o peçam para mudar. “Por muito que me peça, não mudarei” parece ter dois significados: igual a “nem por muito que me peça”, equivalente a “por muito que […]”; se lhe for pedido muito, ele não mudará. Para mim, “por muito que” é mais fraco; se alguém lhe pedir muitíssimo, talvez ele mude. “Nem por muito que” já tem a mesma forma de “por mais que”. Esta é apenas a minha impressão, logo posso estar errado.

Comment: Nunca escutei nem li 'por muito que' no sentido de 'por mais que'. Na frase dos anos e da fortuna, a primeira estrutura possui uma semântica bem distinta da segunda.